# Arrays & Functions

Tags: c, arrays

here's the question : Write a C function that takes an array of integers along with its size as input parameters and compares the sum of even numbers in the array with the sum of odd numbers in the array. If the sum of even numbers is larger, the function returns 1. If the sum of odd numbers is larger, the function returns -1. If both sums are equal, the function returns 0.

And this is what I tried :

```
int Compare(int a[],int sz){
int Esum=0,n,Osum=0,m;
for(int i=0;i<sz,i++){
    if(a[i]%2==0)
    n=a[i];
    sum+=n;
    else 
    m=a[i];
    sum+=m;
}
printf("%d%d\n",Osum,Esum);
if(Esum>Osum)
return 1;
else if(Osum>Esum)
return -1;
else 
return 0;
```

}

But i tried to compute a main to make it complete code but i couldn't can someone help me please :) , you don't have to give me the answer only give me some hints

Comment: Triple equal? What language is this?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting a compilation error? A runtime error? The wrong result?

Comment: sorry it's  typing error @MatteoTassinari

Comment: I need some hints to compute the main for this function @Mureinik

Comment: you never modify the value of `Osum` and `Esum`

Comment: not entirely related, but you should really clean up your code formatting.  writing if/else blocks like that will end up biting you eventually.  tab in the returns/code that runs under each condition, so you can see exactly what's happening each step of the way at a quick glance.

Comment: Don't you have to do i%2 instead of a[i]%2

Comment: the main function should send some data (preferably one that you know the answer to) to the function. like - Compare(array,size), where main would initialize for example: _int array = {0,1,2,3}; int size = 4;_

Comment: wow that's really help me THANK YOU *_* @sagivd

Comment: Can I show you my full code to tell me if there's wrong or not ? @sagivd

Comment: @johnsmith why should we do the testing?  You already have all the tools to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but formatting your code like this (for example) would be a good start:

```
int Compare(int a[],int sz)
{
  int Esum=0,n,Osum=0,m;        // <<< is it Osum or sum

  for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {    //<< NOTE THE ; HERE INSTEAD OF ,
    if (a[i]%2 == 0) {
      n=a[i];
      sum+=n;                   // <<< is it Osum or sum
    }
    else {
      m=a[i];
      sum+=m;                   // <<< is it Osum or sum
    }
  }

  printf("%d %d\n",Osum, Esum);  // <<< space between the two %d

  if (Esum > Osum)
    return 1;
  else if (Osum > Esum)
    return -1;
  else 
   return 0;
}
```

C allows you to put spaces and blank lines in order to improve readability.

It's exactly *your* code with some minor adjustments and some comments. You see the difference in readability?

Comment: nice of you to put the effort :) note the "tu" on the last line.